# Add CAA and SSHFP records to TinyDNS?

Tags: dns

One of the folks I work with is a fan of Bernstein's [TinyDNS](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/tinydns.html), so we run it internally. I'm having trouble figuring to how to add a [CAA record](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6844) and a [SSHFP record](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4255) to the server. There's a page on [Running a DNS Server](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/run-server.html), but it does not state how to add the records.

How do I add CAA and SSHFP records to TinyDNS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the generic record format in tinydns. it allows you to specify the type.

An example is at http://anders.com/projects/sysadmin/djbdnsRecordBuilder/.

Comment: For those who may come along here, Ander's domain has changed:  (https://andersbrownworth.com/projects/sysadmin/djbdnsRecordBuilder)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the entries I use for majid.info:

```
:majid.info:257:\000\005issueletsencrypt.org
:majid.info:257:\000\011issuewildletsencrypt.org
:majid.info:257:\000\005iodefmailto:ssladministrator@majid.org:600
```

corresponding to:

```
CAA 0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
CAA 0 issuewild "letsencrypt.org"
CAA 0 iodef "mailto:ssladministrator@majid.org"
```

Comment: Beware that `iodef` should start with `mailto:`, I think.

Comment: So it does. Thank you very much for catching that, SSLLabs didn't...